# Path to views in menu link

Tags: views, routes, path-aliases

I have a view that shows all the articles then I can select the year. I made this with a group filter.
At this point drupal send the user to an url /noticias?created=2

and here news of 2014 are displayed

and so on..
noticias?created=3 ---> 2013
noticias?created=4 ---> 2012
...

Now I want add a link in the main menu

News 2014 (path: noticias?created=2)

but it says: The path 'noticias' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

The question is

How can I create a menu link for each year? I would not like to use absolute path...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use contextual filters with the year as parameter. Your views path could be "noticias/%". "%" is a placeholder for your contextual filter. So you have to add 2 filter i think. Global: Null and your year date as second parameter. This method is more SEO friendly.